# AutoHotKey - Make image appear relative to a set of moving pixels?

Tags: autohotkey, pixel, always-on-top

Is it possible to create an AHK script that will position a given image (not changing) relative to a different "image" that will be moving constantly on the computer screen? I put the second "image" in quotations because the program would have to constantly search for that "image" or set of pixels that make up that "image" in order to correctly position the first image relative to the second "image".

If it's not possible to do this with AHK, how else can this be done?

The "image" would have to be placed always on top (or above all other programs).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be achieved relatively easily.

You will need to create a [Loop](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) which performs:

1. [Pixel Search](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm)/[Image Search](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm)
2. Using the data retrieved from (1), depending on how the image is displayed using AHK, perform a image move function. If you use a borderless window ([GUI](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm)), you will need [WinMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) function.

See all commands here: [Commands](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands.htm)

Comment: Loop
{

ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, X0, Y0, X1366, Y768, C:\Users\Steven2\Desktop\pic6.png
if ErrorLevel = 0 
} I'm not sure how to do the second part though. Let's say I want the image to be displayed 100 pixels down and 200 pixels to the right of the FoundX, FoundY.

Comment: You would need to do math. So do: FoundX += 200 then do on a line below that FoundY += 100 this will add those values to the FoundX and FoundY values.

Comment: Then create a GUI with an image control like this "GUI, Picture, x0 y0 w100 h100, PATH_TO_IMAGE" then next line, do "GUI, Show, , SomeWindowName" you will need to check under GUI options in the help manual how to hide the border so that only the image shows. Then to move the window, simply use the WinMove command

Comment: I would create the GUI before and  outside the loop and keep the WinMove command inside the loop. Reason being is you want to create the Image window ONLY ONCE whereas the moving part is repeated